# How do you cast a spell?

Tags: talisman

Something seems to be crazy with my game.

I'm playing a wizard, it's the start of my turn and I have the "Nullify" spell (Target one character, remove all their spells)

But all that happens when I select the spell is I get the option to queue the spell; which I can do; but I can't work out how to target the other character and cast it?

According to this

http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=266672118&insideModal=1

It should allow me to cast the spell at next opportunity; but the druid (another character)  has a spell and it never lets me cast it...

Answer (score 1):

This question is difficult to answer definitively without additional information, but there may be multiple in-game effects which would deny your character the ability to cast the spell. This list isn't exhaustive, but any of these would not permit you to cast the spell:

- Your character has the Amulet.
- No other characters have a spell, and the druid has the Amulet.
- Your wizard is on the hidden grove.
- The magic shell or destroy magic spells were cast in the last round.

Overall, it's important to check the lower-left corner when things aren't working as you expect them to. Ongoing effects are usually listed there and that can often be the cause of what looks like a problem, but is actually an in-game effect.

Alternately, this post is from 2015 and the game did have some glitches due to the complexity of the coding. It is possible that you had an issue, which has since been patched.